# My Visual Studio Application runs on vista, Win7 but not xp

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I created a application on vs 2010. It runs on my vista and i think win7, but it will not open on xp for no reason given? Am i  missing something?

Comment: Theres a reason for everything, check the event viewer.

Comment: Yes! Code, more info about your program ...

Comment: What version of the .NET framework are you targetting? How are you deploying the application (xcopy, msi installer)?

Comment: You'll have to provide SOME information for us to work with. Is it a console application? Windows Forms? WPF? Do you get any error message? How about if you run it from the command line? Is a message displayed?

Comment: Is the .net framework installed? In xp is not installed by default! What error did you get?

Comment: Its a forms application. I will confirm the .net version. The i developed on had .net 4.5.It connects to Database on the web via a entity framework. Sorry, event viewer- i do not know what viewer you are referring to here. The only error message: EventType:clr20r3; then p1 to p whatever with hex although i do get p4:system.drawing which could signify a conflict of some kind.

Comment: I checked my xp machine and it seemed to be .net 4. I installed .net 4 anyways. My application was build using .net 4 client profile but i produced a version target to .net 4 specifically. Same Error again.

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history#.NET_Framework_4.5

.NET 4.5 is only supported on Vista or later.

**Edit:**

You might want to change your "Target framework": `Project > Properties > Application > Target framework` to something earlier, like .NET 4 (and make sure you install .NET 4 before wondering why it still doesn't work)

Comment: Question tag contains `visual-studio-2010` not 2012.

Comment: @Matthew Matters little, unless VS 2010 doesn't allow to manually set the target framework, which would be stupid. I only gave an example using VS 2012 since I don't have VS 2010 available. It's actually not difficult to ask Google `How to set target framework on VS 2010`, hell; Google even spared me the trouble of typing it all in!

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 cannot make projects that target `.net 4.5`, maximum of `.net 4.0`, which XP supports.

Comment: I checked my xp machine and it seemed to be .net 4. I installed .net 4 anyways. My application was build using .net 4 client profile but i produced a version target to .net 4 specifically. Same Error again.